# Unable to load CSS with Internet Explorer Conditional Comment

Tags: css, internet-explorer

The file contains only a color of green for the text. When I run the page, text remains black. If I move the "link rel..." outside of the comment block it will then load text as green.

```
<!--[if IE ]>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_css/ie_only.css"/>
<![endif]-->
```

How is this to be written in order for it to load only for Internet Explorer?

Comment: "If you need special styles for IE10 or up you’ll have to find another method, since conditional comments were disabled in IE10." (Source: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html)

Comment: Which version of `IE`?

Comment: Apparently as IE is now up to scratch with y'know, being a decent web browser, conditional comments are no more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that I have IE 10 and as 'Alexander' has pointed out it does not support conditional comments. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Unless its a folder name...Remove `_` from `href` and space after `IE`!!!

```
<!--[if IE]>
         ^^ space was here
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ie_only.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: CSS is successfully loaded with `_` (outside conditional comment)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the trailing space after IE